# Copy Files and pasting them in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

So what i'm trying to do is get a selected file from File explorer, and copy it then paste it into a new folder via a batch file upon clicking it....is there a way?

Comment: What do you mean by "past it via a batch file upon clicking it"?  Do you want to click on the batch file? or the folder? or paste into a folder.  Very Unclear!

Comment: I mean I want the ability to click on the batch.  then once it runs to select a file and have it copy and paste to a already defined folder

Comment: Batch scripts have no integration with Windows File Explorer, and have no obvious way to know what file you may have selected via File Explorer.  So unless someone has a creative way to get the current selection from File Explorer, the answer is **No**.

Comment: Your options are dragging and dropping the file onto the batch file or creating a right click context menu for the batch file so that it sends it to that batch file.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think about you doing that is by creating a some sort of data base thing
For Example

```
@echo off
:fileSelect
echo Which folder do you want?
set /p folderName= 
goto %folderName%
```

You can do it that way. Then you will have to manually put in the locations the files like so

```
:"Files Name here"
copy C:\"Files location" C:\"Designated location to paste file"
goto fileSelect
```

That's one simple way of doing it. If that's not exactly what you want or if its unclear let me know and I will attempt to help you find another way to do it.

Comment: what happens `if %foldername% == folder with space`?